# getting XML value in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql, xml-parsing

I have the following xml in one of column in table on postgres database (it is workflow in jira):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE workflow PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//DTD OSWorkflow 2.8//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd">
<workflow>
    ...
  <steps>
    <step id="1" name="New">
        ...
    </step>
    <step id="5" name="Resolved">
        ...
    </step>
    <step id="10" name="Closed">
        ...
    </step>
  </steps>
  ...
</workflow>
```

I want to select mappings:

```
1 - New
5 - Resolved
10 - Closed
```

How to achive that? Which postgres functions should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `xpath` [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html).

```
select
  unnest(xpath('//workflow/steps/step/@id', xmlin)),
  unnest(xpath('//workflow/steps/step/@name', xmlin))
from
  (select xmlparse(document '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE workflow PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//DTD OSWorkflow 2.8//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd">
<workflow>
  <steps>
    <step id="1" name="New">
    </step>
    <step id="5" name="Resolved">
    </step>
    <step id="10" name="Closed">
    </step>
  </steps>
</workflow>') xmlin) x

----
1;New
5;Resolved
10;Closed
```

Note - As pointed out by @posz, this won't work if `name` or `id` attribute is missing.

Comment: Surprising results can happen if multiple set-returning function used in the `SELECT` clause, especially if they have different row numbers. In this case, f.ex. if a step node only has `id` **or** `name` attribute, but not both.

Comment: @pozs Technically you are correct, but I don't think you can have missing `name` or `id` attribute in JIRA workflow.

Answer (score 0):

To process xml nodes, you can use the [`xpath()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) function:

```
with v(x) as (
  select xmlparse(document '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE workflow PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//DTD OSWorkflow 2.8//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd">
<workflow><steps><step id="1" name="New"/><step id="5" name="Resolved"/><step id="10" name="Closed"/></steps></workflow>')
)
select (xpath('@id', step))[1] as id, (xpath('@name', step))[1] as name
from v
cross join lateral unnest(xpath('/workflow/steps/step', x)) as step
```

The result columns will by typed `xml`, so casting may be needed.